# How to move from one view controller to another Automatically with some time?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nstimer, splash-screen

I am new to this development and i was working with splash screen but I don't know how to move from one view controller to another with some certain time...

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"nameOfYourSegue" sender:self];
```

I don't know how to add time any help please.....

Comment: use perform selector perform(#selector(yourFunction), with: nil, afterDelay: 1)

Comment: @karthikeyan can you please explain why and how?

Comment: So I don't need to use     [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"nameOfYourSegue" sender:self];

Comment: You have to use it as well Read more https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1416176-performselector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
// delay 1 second

dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 1.0 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueID" sender:nil];
});
```

**OR**

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 1.0 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

    UIViewController*vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"VCID"];

    [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[Timer Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/timer)

```
Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 5, repeats: false) { (timer) in
      self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "nameOfYourSegue", sender: nil)
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in viewDidLoad

```
[self performSelector:@selector(LoadMainPage:) withObject:nil afterDelay:3.0];
```

and then,

```
-(void)LoadLoginPage
{
  LoginViewController *loginView=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"loginViewController"];
  [self.navigationController pushViewController:loginView animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display a splash screen before your initial view controller, you should read the Apple's [Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/icons-and-images/launch-screen/).

Also, here is a simple [tutorial](https://www.appcoda.com/how-to-add-splash-screen-in-your-ios-app/) to help you create your own splash screen.

Happy coding ;)